# Could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to write a Mapper that would convert Option[sql.Date] to Option[sql.Timestamp]. For this, I am using the following code:

```
package model.db

import java.sql.Date

import com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.simple._

abstract class RichTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String, schema: Option[String] = Some("dbo")) extends Table[T](tag, schema, name) {
  def id: Column[Option[Long]] = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def cancelled: Column[Option[Date]] = column[Option[Date]]("cancelled")(DateMapper.sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper)
}

abstract class LoggableTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String, schema: Option[String] = Some("dbo")) extends RichTable[T](tag, name, schema) {
  def createdAt: Column[Date] = column[Date]("created_at", O.NotNull)(DateMapper.sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper)
}

object DateMapper {
  val sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper = MappedColumnType.base[java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp](
    { sqlDate => new java.sql.Timestamp(sqlDate.getTime) },
    { sqlTimestamp => new java.sql.Date(sqlTimestamp.getTime) })

  val sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper = MappedColumnType.base[scala.Option[java.sql.Date], scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp]](
    { sqlDate => scala.Some(new java.sql.Timestamp(sqlDate.get.getTime)) },
    { sqlTimestamp => scala.Some(new java.sql.Date(sqlTimestamp.get.getTime)) })
}
```

The **sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper** works fine, so I used it as a base code for the **sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper**.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

> Error:(21, 126) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter
> of type
> com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.BaseColumnType[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]]
> val sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper =
> MappedColumnType.base[scala.Option[java.sql.Date],
> scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp]](
>
> Error:(21, 126) not enough
> arguments for method base: (implicit evidence$5:
> scala.reflect.ClassTag[Option[java.sql.Date]], implicit evidence$6:
> com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.BaseColumnType[Option[java.sql.Timestamp]])com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.BaseColumnType[Option[java.sql.Date]].
> Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.   val
> sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper =
> MappedColumnType.base[scala.Option[java.sql.Date],
> scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp]](

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @pamu said, there is no need for a mapper for an Option. The stacktrace was complaining for a implicit value; so what I did was make the mapper implict, and the problem was solved.

```
package model.db

import java.sql.Date

import com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.simple._

abstract class RichTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String, schema: Option[String] = Some("dbo")) extends Table[T](tag, schema, name) {
  def id: Column[Option[Long]] = column[Option[Long]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def cancelled: Column[Option[Date]] = column[Option[Date]]("cancelled")
}

abstract class LoggableTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String, schema: Option[String] = Some("dbo")) extends RichTable[T](tag, name, schema) {
  def createdAt: Column[Date] = column[Date]("created_at", O.NotNull)
}

object DateMapper {
  implicit val sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper = MappedColumnType.base[java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp](
    { sqlDate => new java.sql.Timestamp(sqlDate.getTime) },
    { sqlTimestamp => new java.sql.Date(sqlTimestamp.getTime) })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need option mapper. Remove this piece of code.

```
val sqlDate2SqlTimestampOptionMapper = MappedColumnType.base[scala.Option[java.sql.Date], scala.Option[java.sql.Timestamp]](
    { sqlDate => scala.Some(new java.sql.Timestamp(sqlDate.get.getTime)) },
    { sqlTimestamp => scala.Some(new java.sql.Date(sqlTimestamp.get.getTime)) })
```

Now your date mapper becomes

```
object DateMapper {
  val sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper = MappedColumnType.base[java.sql.Date, java.sql.Timestamp](
    { sqlDate => new java.sql.Timestamp(sqlDate.getTime) },
    { sqlTimestamp => new java.sql.Date(sqlTimestamp.getTime) })
}
```

In Slick if you give mapping for some `T` then you need not implement mapping for `Option[T]`

Comment: I did this at first. But I got a type mismatch error: 

Error:(9, 86) type mismatch;
 found   : com.typesafe.slick.driver.ms.SQLServerDriver.BaseColumnType[java.sql.Date]
    (which expands to)  scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcType[java.sql.Date] with scala.slick.ast.BaseTypedType[java.sql.Date]
 required: scala.slick.ast.TypedType[Option[java.sql.Date]]
  def cancelled: Column[Option[Date]] = column[Option[Date]]("cancelled")(DateMapper.sqlDate2SqlTimestampMapper)

Comment: @RafaelTSCS can you share the solution you found ?

Comment: Done! The problem was that the mapper wasn't implicit.